# Dyn.load unable to load object compiled with -fopenmp Rcpp

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I am using g++ (GCC) 4.6.1 to compile my Rcpp package. However with -fopenmp option it is giving error in "dyn.load" (unable to load *.so). Without -fopenmp package INSTALL smoothly. I am using latest Rcpp . The only warning during the compilation is:

```
compiler_setup.hpp:169:110: note: #pragma message: Your C++ compiler is in C++11 mode, but it has incomplete support for C++11 features 
.so: undefined symbol: dsyevd_
```

The R version is 3.0.2 Patched (2013-10-11 r64042). My other c-code that don't use Rcpp works fine with -fopenmp. The g++ run by installation is

```
 g++  -DNDEBUG -DUSE_R -DNDEBUG -DDISABLE_SINGLE -DNTHROW -DDISABLE_FIO -I/usr/local/include -I"./3.0/Rcpp/include"  -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O3 -pipe -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -c eQTL.cpp -o eQTL.o
```

Comment: What does it print in the dyn.load error? What symbols is it unable to resolve? Or is it something else?

Comment: It giving unidefined symbol: *.so: undefined symbol: dsyevd_

Comment: That's an LAPACK function, so I imagine you need `-llapack` somewhere in your arguments, plus a `-L/path/to/LAPACK` (probably the R version). E.g. try `R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS` in the terminal to find it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but it is giving new error Symbol not found: __ZN4Rcpp5RcoutE

Comment: To be explicit: are you trying to install this package with `R CMD build <pkg>; R CMD INSTALL <tarball>`? You probably need `LinkingTo: Rcpp` and `Imports: Rcpp` in your package's `DESCRIPTION` file, plus an `importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)` in your `NAMESPACE`. See the [release notes](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/) on Dirk's blog, and the [Rcpp-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf) vignette.

Comment: As Kevin said. As once it works as a package, adding OpenMP should be a breeze.